# Golang backend to javascript JSON Parse

Tags: javascript, json, go, websocket

I am using the gorilla websocket library for golang: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket

This is the code I am using to create the websocket connection:

```
conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
```

Having an issue with sending JSON from golang to javascript. I can get it working but have to do what seem to be unnecessary steps.  Here is the basics of the golang backend that does not work:

```
    type clientDB struct{
         ChunksWritten int64
         ChunksRead int64
         BytesWritten   int64
         BytesRead    int64
         DataBytesWritten int64
         DataBytesRead    int64
         ActivePeers   int
         TotalPeers    int
         TorrentHashString string
}

fullClientDB := new(clientDB) //creating a new clientDB struct

b, err := json.Marshal(fullClientDB)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }


conn.WriteJSON(b)
```

When I use JSON.parse in javascript I get the following response:

```
var clientUpdate = JSON.parse(evt.data);
```

> eyJDaHVua3NXcml0dGVuIjowLCJDaHVua3NSZWFkIjowLCJCeXRlc1dyaXR0ZW4iOjU0NDgxLCJCeXRlc1JlYWQiOjc4NzgyLCJEYXRhQnl0ZXNXcml0dGVuIjowLCJEYXRhQnl0ZXNSZWFkIjowLCJBY3RpdmVQZWVycyI6MCwiVG90YWxQZWVycyI6NDMsIlRvcnJlbnRIYXNoU3RyaW5nIjoiOWY5MTY1ZDlhMjgxYTliOGU3ODJjZDUxNzZiYmNjODI1NmZkMTg3MSJ9

I can get it working making the following changes:

```
conn.WriteJSON(string(b))
```

Then in javascript I actually parse the data TWICE.

```
var clientUpdate = JSON.parse(evt.data);
var clientUpdateJSON = JSON.parse(clientUpdate);
```

After that I can access the data correctly as a JSON object.  Is there something I'm missing about sending JSON objects from golang to javascript over websockets?

Comment: Somewhere you are `base64` encoding the data. The string you posted after base64 decode is `{"ChunksWritten":0,"ChunksRead":0,"BytesWritten":54481,"BytesRead":78782,"DataBytesWritten":0,"DataBytesRead":0,"ActivePeers":0,"TotalPeers":43,"TorrentHashString":"9f9165d9a281a9b8e782cd5176bbcc8256fd1871"}`

Comment: I don't know what kind of `conn` has a `WriteJSON` method, but it looks like you're taking a slice which is already JSON, and encoding it again as JSON, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the library I am using: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket

This is creating the connection: `conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)`

Comment: Then only use `WriteJSON` _or_ `json.Marshal`; you don't need to encode it twice.

Comment: Interesting that it `base64` encodes it if sent to both...

Comment: Thanks, in retrospect I should have realized that the reason they had a "writejson" function was to encode as well as write to the websocket, otherwise why have that function at all.  Thanks!

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: base64 is the default json encoding format for a `[]byte`

Comment: @JimB Cool! Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gorilla websocket [package](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket,%20package) automatically encodes to JSON so using the standard library to encode as well was just encoding it twice, causing it to show up as base64.

Thanks guys!